# SQL addition with join that can return nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server

`Table1` and `Table2` both contain columns named `Username` and `Score`. `Table1` is guaranteed to have all users needed for the query, while `Table2` has only a subset of those users. How do I write this query such that I always get the total score of both tables even if Table2 doesn't contain a matching user? In otherwords, if null in Table2 I want to treat it as a zero.

```
            Table1    Table2
User1       200       100
User2       200       NULL
User3       200       300

User1 TotalScore = 300
User2 TotalScore = 200
User3 TotalScore = 500
```

Comment: Is the username unique in each of the tables or can one or both of the tables contain multiple entries for a user?

Answer (score 4):

I think a simple aggregation would do the trick

```
Select UserName
      ,Score=sum(Score)
 From (
        Select UserName,Score From Table1
        Union All
        Select UserName,Score From Table2
      ) A
 Group By UserName
```

Answer (score 3):

use COALESCE for null check and left join with table 2

```
select username, COALESCE(Table1,0) + COALESCE( Table2,0) from t
```

so complete query will be

```
    select t1.username,t1.value as table1_value,
   t2.value as table2_value,
   COALESCE(t1.value,0) + COALESCE( t2.value,0) as TotalScore
   from t1 left join t2 on t1.username =t2.username
```

Answer (score 1):

`LEFT JOIN` will guarantee that you will get all users from `Table1`.
If particular user doesn't exist in `Table2`, value from this table for the user will be `NULL`, to treat it as 0, you need to use `COALESCE`.

Try this:

```
select t1.username, 
       t1.score,
       t2.score,
       t1.score + coalesce(t2.score, 0) totalScore
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.username = t2.username
```

Answer (score 1):

Use left join for joining and coalesce for merging NULLS into 0.